# Why my get css width doesn't work?

Tags: android, jquery, css, ipad

I have this and I keep getting Undefined. or null

```
alert('size='+$('.slide1-text-wrap').css('width'));
```

It should be returning a percentage.

I should mention that this only happens on iPad and Android. On desktop works fine. 
So if the width is in pixels, I can get it on iPad or Android, but if the width is in percentage it would return null

Comment: Are you trying to get the actual pixel width? if so, you'd want to use .width() rather than .css('width')

Comment: ok that's weird but it worked. thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked.  It's probably because .css('width') returns whatever is set in css, with units (eg: '50%') where-as .width() returns the actual calculated pixel width.  Not sure why you'd get null or undefined though but at least it's working now.